# Woocommerce "My Account" "Address Field" Display

Tags: php, html, arrays, wordpress, account

I'm creating some custom Woocommerce My Account Pages. Everything's going great, and I run into a troublesome little chunk of code that I can't get through.

My goal is to simply add spacing between the output of the `$address = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_address_formatted_address', ...`

Currently, it populates `<br>` (not even `<br />`) tags between the field values. I really want to be able to replace the `<br>` tags with `<p>` tags. That's it.  It would be nice if I could understand how to add whatever I wanted between them, but that's not as important.

So, here are the pieces:

```
<address>
        <?php
            $address = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_address_formatted_address', array(
                'first_name'  => get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_first_name', true ),
                'last_name'   => get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_last_name', true ),
                'company'     => get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_company', true ),
                'address_1'   => get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_address_1', true ),
                'address_2'   => get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_address_2', true ),
                'city'        => get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_city', true ),
                'state'       => get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_state', true ),
                'postcode'    => get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_postcode', true ),
                'country'     => get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_country', true )
            ), $customer_id, $name );

            $formatted_address = WC()->countries->get_formatted_address( $address );

            if ( ! $formatted_address )
                _e( 'You have not set up this type of address yet.', 'woocommerce' );
            else
                echo $formatted_address;
        ?>
    </address>
```

This then outputs the following:

```
<address>
        John Doe<br>John's Company<br>35 John Street<br>Johnsville, JD 55555
</address>
```

Anyone with me? I am a PHP novice, for sure - so if this is really simple, then bear with me. I just haven't found a solution anywhere regarding this. Usually, I can weasle my way through this kind of stuff.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a little old but I was having the exact same problem and managed to solve it by playing around with the regex that preg_match() searches for.

All I did was change the `$pattern` variable and wrap the `$output` in `<p></p>` tags. The final code is:

```
$address = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_address_formatted_address', array(
        'first_name'  => get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_first_name', true ),
        'last_name'   => get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_last_name', true ),
        'company'     => get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_company', true ),
        'address_1'   => get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_address_1', true ),
        'address_2'   => get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_address_2', true ),
        'city'        => get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_city', true ),
        'state'       => get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_state', true ),
        'postcode'    => get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_postcode', true ),
        'country'     => get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_country', true )
    ), $customer_id, $name );

    $formatted_address = WC()->countries->get_formatted_address( $address );

    if ( ! $formatted_address )
        _e( 'You have not set up this type of address yet.', 'woocommerce' );
    else
        $pattern = "/<br\/>/";
        $replacements= '<p>';
        $formatted_address = WC()->countries->get_formatted_address( $address );
        $output = preg_replace($pattern, $replacements, $formatted_address);
        echo "<p>" . $output . "</p>";
```

Answer (score 0):

If this is what you want

```
<address>
        John Doe,John's Company,35 John Street,Johnsville, JD 55555
</address>
```

then try this:

```
<address>
    <?php
        $address = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_address_formatted_address', array(
            'first_name'  => get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_first_name', true ),
            'last_name'   => get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_last_name', true ),
            'company'     => get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_company', true ),
            'address_1'   => get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_address_1', true ),
            'address_2'   => get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_address_2', true ),
            'city'        => get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_city', true ),
            'state'       => get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_state', true ),
            'postcode'    => get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_postcode', true ),
            'country'     => get_user_meta( $customer_id, $name . '_country', true )
        ), $customer_id, $name );

        $formatted_address = WC()->countries->get_formatted_address( $address );

        if ( ! $formatted_address )
            _e( 'You have not set up this type of address yet.', 'woocommerce' );
        else
            $pattern = '/<br>/';
            $replacements= ',';
            $formatted_address = WC()->countries->get_formatted_address( $address );
            $output = preg_replace($pattern, $replacements, $formatted_address);
            echo $output;
    ?>
</address>
```

Comment: Thanks for responding! I apologize for not getting back to you for so long. Unfortunately, this didn't do the trick. In fact, I'm still left with <br> tags. This seems like there is only a minor flaw in the logic, though. I can't see it.   Maybe something with the pattern string?

Comment: It's starting to work with a tweak.  I replaced the ',' with '<p>' so that it looks like this:
$replacements='<p>';
I've taken away the '/'s from around the <br> tag so that it looks like this:  
$pattern = '<br>' 
and now my output is producing this:
John Doe&lt;<p>/&gt;John's Company&lt;</p><p>/&gt;35 John St&lt;</p><p>/&gt;Johnsonville, JD 555555</p></address>